# modeling reinforcement learning environment with Ray

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been playing around with the idea of using reinforcement learning on a particular problem in which I am optimizing a raw materials purchasing strategy for a particular commodity. I have created a simple gym environment to show a simplified version of what I'd like to accomplish. The goal is to take in multiple items (in this case 2) and optimize a purchasing strategy for each item so that the sum of days on hand of all items are minimized without running out of either item.

```
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, Tuple
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

#define our variable starting points


#array of the start quantity for 2 seperate items
start_qty = np.array([10000, 200])
#create the number of simulation weeks
sim_weeks = 1
#set a starting safety stock level------INGORE FOR NOW
#safety_stock = 4003

#create simple demand profile for each item
#demand = np.array([301, 1549, 3315, 0, 1549, 0, 0, 1549, 1549, 1549])
demand = np.array([1800, 45])

#create minimum order and max order quantities for each item
min_ord = np.array([26400, 250])
max_ord = np.array([100000, 100000])
prev_30_usage = np.array([1600, 28])


#how this works is it in the numpy arrays- the stuff in index 0 is the first item's info
# and the stuff in index 1 is the second item's info
class ResinEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Tuple([Discrete(2), Discrete(2)])
        self.observation_space = Box(low= np.array([-10000000]), high = np.array([10000000]))
        #set the start qty
        self.state = np.array([10000, 200])
        #self.start = start_qty
        #set the purchase length
        self.purchase_length = sim_weeks
        self.min_order = min_ord
    def step(self, action):
        self.purchase_length -= 1
        #apply action 
        self.state[0] -=demand[0]
        self.state[1] -= demand[1]
        #see if we need to buy
        #action is between 0 and 1- round the action to the nearest tenth
        action = np.around(action, decimals = 0)
        
        
        #self.state +=action*self.min_order
        
        np.add(self.state, action* self.min_order, out=self.state, casting="unsafe")
        #self.state += (action*100) + 26400
        #calculate the days on hand from this
        days = self.state/prev_30_usage/7
        
        
        #item_reward1 = action[0]
        #item_reward2 = action[1]
        #calculate reward: right now reward is negative of days_on_hand
        
        #GOING TO NEED TO CHANGE THIS REWARD AT SOME POINT MOVING FORWARD AS IT
        #NEEDS TO TREAT HIGH VOLUME ITEMS AND LOW VOLUME ITEMS THE SAME- THIS IS BIASED AGAINST LOW VOLUME
        if self.state[0] < 0:
            item_reward1 = -10000
        else:
            item_reward1 = days[0]
        if self.state[1]< 0:
            item_reward2 = -10000
        else:
            item_reward2 = days[1]
        
        reward = item_reward1 + item_reward2
        #check if we are out of weeks
        if self.purchase_length<=0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        #reduce the weeks left to purchase by 1 week
        #done = True   
        #set placeholder for info
        info = {}
            
        #return step information
        return self.state, reward, done, info
    def render(self):
        pass
    def reset(self):
        self.state = np.array([10000, 200])
        self.purchase_length = sim_weeks
        self.demand = demand
        self.action_space = Tuple([Discrete(2), Discrete(2)])
        self.min_order= min_ord
        return self.state #, self.purchase_length, self.demand, self.action_space, self.min_order
```

The environment seems to be functioning just fine as seen with this code:

```
episodes = 100
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    
    while not done:
        #env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{} Action:{}'.format(episode, score, action))
```

I have attempted to run this through various ways of modeling with no luck and have discovered Ray but can't seem to get that to work either. I was wondering if someone could walk me through the process of modeling in Ray- or help identify any issues with the environment itself that would cause Ray to not work. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am new to RL and completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in RL and was search for some code and  find yours

it seams you need only define env due to i add this line and it is worked

```
....
episodes = 100
env = ResinEnv()
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
state = env.reset()
done = False
score = 0 
....
```

hope it is useful